# Table is not contracting

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please take a look at this video, it explains my problem:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zeq_BZ5QgCg

It's a simple table. When I resize the page, the table resizes with the page to some point, but then stops.

I have no idea why the table behaves like that. I want it to contract just like the rest of the page.

The black lines you see are from div containers that are set to "clear:both".

The html code of the table:

```
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center" id="videoevent">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="thead" align="center" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:center">
  Headline
 </td>

 </tr><tr>

 <td class="alt2" align="center" style="padding:10px;">

  <div class="right" style="margin:5px 0px 10px 0px"><span id="user_online_count">refreshing...</span> persons are viewing this page</div>

  <div class="left" style="margin:5px 0px 10px 0px">OVERVIEW</div>

  <div class="c"></div>


  <div class="overviewcontainer" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <a href="./?room=1">
   <img src="/thumbs/test.jpg" class="overview-img" height="200" alt="" border="0" />
   <span class="img-headline">Jade</span>
   <span class="offline_indicator" id="oi_model_1">offline</span>  
  </a>

  </div><div class="overviewcontainer" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <a href="./?room=2">
   <img src="/thumbs/test.jpg" class="overview-img" height="200" alt="" border="0" />
   <span class="img-headline">User</span>
   <span class="offline_indicator" id="oi_model_2">offline</span>
  </a>

  </div><div class="overviewcontainer" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <a href="./?room=3">
   <img src="/thumbs/test.jpg" class="overview-img" height="200" alt="" border="0" />
   <span class="img-headline">User</span>
   <span class="offline_indicator" id="oi_model_3">offline</span>  
  </a>

  </div><div class="overviewcontainer" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <a href="./?room=4">
   <img src="/thumbs/test.jpg" class="overview-img" height="200" alt="" border="0" />
   <span class="img-headline">XXX</span>
   <span class="offline_indicator" id="oi_model_4">offline</span>
  </a>

  </div><div class="overviewcontainer" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <a href="./?room=5">
   <img src="/thumbs/test.jpg" class="overview-img" height="200" alt="" border="0" />
   <span class="img-headline">admin</span>
   <span class="offline_indicator" id="oi_model_5">offline</span>
  </a>

 </div>

 <div class="c"></div>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
 Viewers: <span id="users_in_chat">waiting for refresh</span>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I see nothing in the style of the table that could cause this behavior:

```
td[align=center] {
text-align: -webkit-center;
}
td[valign=middle] {
vertical-align: middle;
}
element.style {
}
.thead {
background: #CA1B03;
color: white;
font: normal normal bold 11px/normal tahoma, verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
td, th, p, li {
font: normal normal normal 10pt/normal verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*user agent stylesheet*/
td, th {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: inherit;
}
Inherited from table#videoevent.tborder
.tborder {
color: black;
}
/*user agent stylesheet*/
table {
border-spacing: 2px 2px;
border-collapse: separate;
}
/*Inherited from div.dynwrap.page*/
Style Attribute {
text-align: left;
}
.page {
color: black;
}
/*Inherited from body*/
body {
color: black;
font: normal normal normal 10pt/normal verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: And your real CSS. That looks like the output of a DOM inspector.

Comment: I have updated the post with the full table. It must be caused by something inside the table. The CSS is from a DOM inspector indeed. I know you should not use div containers in tables. But the table allows me to easily have two boxes at 50% side-by-side (on a different page that uses the same template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe cause that there are some nowrap elements or elements with fixed width inside `td` elements? Video, images or `style="white-space: nowrap;"`?

Comment: I found the problem. It was related to the contents of the div containers. I set them to hide the overflow, but for some reason they still expanded the table.

Comment: I am glad for you. May be you should try to use `overflow: auto;` and fixed width as compromise solution?